# Why did React "restart" the render-phase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sandbox link : [Link to This CodeSandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-visvesvaraya-bfhxu8?file=/src/App.js)

Please help me understand the sequence of execution in this code.

When an error is thrown in child component ( `Display` ), the getDerivedStateFromError() runs and sets `hasError` state to `true`. After that, as expected `render()` runs....

What I didn't understand is.... Why is the `constructor` being called again ? This is counter-intuitive... Please explain the reason for its calling...

What did React achieve by restarting everything from the constructor ? It should've simply displayed the fallback UI..But it ran the constructor again and only after facing the same error again did it show the fallback UI. Why did this happen ?

[image: why is constructor being called again ?]

This is my App.js file

```
import React from "react";

export const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <button className={props.className} onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

function Display(props) {
  throw new Error();
  return <h1>Counter {props.i}</h1>;
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("constr ran");
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      updated: false,
      firstRender: false,
      hasError: false,
    };
    this.incHandler = this.incHandler.bind(this);
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError() {
    console.log("getDerivedStateFromError Ran...");
    return {
      hasError: true,
    };
  }

  incHandler() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count + 1,
        updated: true,
      };
    });
    console.log(this.state.count);
  }

  decHandler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count - 1,
        updated: true,
      };
    });
    console.log(this.state.count);
  };

  render() {
    console.log("render() ran... hasError: ", this.state.hasError);
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Error happened!</h1>;
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Display i={this.state.count} />
        <Button className="button" onClick={this.incHandler}>
          Increment
        </Button>
        <Button className="button" onClick={this.decHandler}>
          Decrement
        </Button>
        <Button
          className="button"
          onClick={() => {
            throw new Error();
          }}
        >
          This Will Throw Error
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

This is my index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);

reportWebVitals();
```

Just wanted to add more to this....

Even when `componentDidCatch()` is used to catch errors in child components,
Behaviour of React is same...

Please see below image and code
[image: componentDidCatch() also causes "restart" of render phase]

In App.js I made this small modification. This is also causing re-running of constructor.... Why ?

```
 // static getDerivedStateFromError() {
  //   console.log("getDerivedStateFromError Ran...");
  //   return {
  //     hasError: true,
  //   };
  // }

  componentDidCatch() {
    console.log("componentDidCatch running");
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
  }
```

So, apparently, whenever React encounters an error it tries to start everything from constructor...(with the hope of eliminating it...)  It sure looks like that....

Comment: In the end... it did show the fallback ui... But why did it have to run the constructor again... that is the part I didn't understand.

Comment: Let me guess – you're running in StrictMode, which runs things multiple times.

Comment: No it is not in StrictMode.

Comment: Can you just make a reproducible example in a sandbox? And btw notice that the usage of constructor is not recommended, it also mentioned in the docs, use class properties syntax instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-visvesvaraya-bfhxu8?file=/src/App.js

Here is the sandbox link... Same behavior here too....

Comment: Btw... I noticed that StrictMode has no effect on this.